# IE7 won't show my website entirely

Tags: html, internet-explorer-7

I find myself in a pickle, I hope someone can help.

I have a website and if I open this website in any browser out there it works perfectly find until I open it with IE7. IE7 opens the website however it only load half of it... the html source code is downloaded successfully and the elements in the background are active, they are just not visible to clients o.O what can I do??

The website is: http://ambulanta-susnik.voblaku.com/

I'm not trying to advertise in ANY WAY. I just fell like this is the only way to really show you whats wrong.

Try opening it in IE7 or IE9 with Document type: IE7 standards.

Any ideas??? I tried everything ... different doctypes, xmls declaration, xml declaration, etc...

W3C HTML validator shows 5 Errors, 5 warning(s) but those are only for unencoded links...

Screenshots for those who can't use IE7 compatibility mode:

WRONG WAY: http://ambulanta-susnik.voblaku.com/files/wrong.png

RIGHT WAY: http://ambulanta-susnik.voblaku.com/files/right.png

Comment: IE7 is the new IE6. Consider it garbage, treat it as such, and move on.

Comment: I want to but I can't! My boss wants this fixed. I really need a quick fix or something...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add `position:relative` to the `#content {}` css

Comment: It works ... wait ... what just happend??? How did that fix the problem? Actually I don't really want to know. Thank you very much!